# TinyMCE 4.7.4 does not work with URL that contains query string parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, tinymce

I am integrating TinyMCE 4.7.4 into ASP.NET 4.6.1 web page called Contacts.aspx
I find that if I browse to Contacts.aspx without query string parameter like

```
https://www.example.com/Contacts.aspx
```

TinyMCE  works correctly.

However, if I browse to Contacts.aspx with query string parameter like

```
https://www.example.com/Contacts.aspx?CompanyCode=J23N162&Language=English
```

TinyMCE  does not work correctly and Javascript is rendered correctly to HTML but does not run in the browser Chrome.

Could any one tell me how to make TinyMCE to work with URL that contain query string parameters?
Thank your help in advance.
Yu Hang

Comment: The contents of a query string have nothing to do with loading the TinyMCE JavaScript and running the `init()` function.  If adding those breaks things you will need to look at exactly what is broken, what error messages you are getting, and why the query string has any impact at all on that page.  In and of itself the query string's existence in the URL is not causing TinyMCE to not load as TinyMCE won't know anything about the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Adding string parameters to a URL will have no impact on how or when TinyMCE is loaded in your browser. Perhaps the root cause is somewhere further up the loading hierarchy?